# PHP & ZipArchive() - Failed to load PDF document

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, php-ziparchive

Good afternon, i have a form that in determined field it open a window or windows to display a specific PDF. The folder where is the path, it can there is just a PDF or a ZIP file with multiples PDF's inner according to the input filled value.

This is blur() event part on the whole my code that calls the windows and pass the values to the "arquivo.php" and "pdf.php", one is to check if is just a PDF or a ZIP, if was a PDF this return on my form informing that is a PDF just and after open just a window to display, this part is ok

JavaScript/HTML code:

```
///////////PASS THE VALUES TO "arquivo.php"////////////////
     $.post("arquivo.php", {nprocesso: document.getElementById("processo").value}, function(data){
        $( "#content3" ).html( data ); /*<-- return in this content if is a PDF or a ZIP(when is a zip it returns how many PDF's there are inner ZIP file too)*/

    ////////////THIS PART IS TO CREATE JUST A WINDOW OR MULTIPLES WINDOWS PASSING THE VALUES RETURNED IN THE "content3" TO "pdf.php" TO DISPLAY IT/THEM//////////////////    
    setTimeout(function(){
               if(document.getElementById("content3").innerText == "PDF"){
                  window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800"); 
               }else{
                  var QuantPDF = Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.lastIndexOf(','))+1, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length));//Number(document.getElementById("content3").innerText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
                  var NomesPDFS = []; NomesPDFS = document.getElementById("content3").innerText.slice(3, document.getElementById("content3").innerText.length-2).split(',');
                  if(QuantPDF > 1){
                   for(var i = 0; i < QuantPDF; i++){
                    window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value+"/"+NomesPDFS[i], '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");  
                   }   
                  }else{
                   window.open("pdf.php/"+document.getElementById("processo").value, '_blank', "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=800");    
                  }
               }
              document.getElementById('closeBtn').click();
              }, 1000);
            }
```

This is the "arquivo.php", where check if is just a PDF or a ZIP file, and extract if was a zip

Arquivo.php code:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  //////////THIS PART CHECK THAT FILE IS A PDF AND RETURN TO MY JAVASCRIPT CODE/////////
  if(file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'.pdf')){

    echo 'PDF';
    $_SESSION['file'] = "PDF";

  }else{

//////////THIS PART CHECK THAT FILE IS A ZIP AND RETURN TO MY JAVASCRIPT CODE/////////

    echo 'ZIP';
    $_SESSION['file'] = "ZIP";
     $zip = new ZipArchive;
     $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'.zip';
     ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      if($zip->open($path) === true){
       //////////THIS PART IT OPENS THE ZIP AND EXTRACT/////////
if(!file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'])){
            mkdir('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'], 0777, true);
           }
            for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++){
             $zip->extractTo('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'], array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
             $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'];
             $files = scandir($path); array_shift($files); array_shift($files);
             $file = array(); $filename = array();
        ///////NOW I CATCH THE PDF's NAMES AND THE QUANTITY AND RETURN TO JAVASCRIPT CODE///////
             $file[$i] = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'/'.$files[$i];
             $filename[$i] = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'].'/'.$files[$i];
             $nomes_pdfs = array();
             $nomes_pdfs[$i] = substr(substr($filename[$i], strpos($filename[$i], $_POST['nprocesso'])+26, strlen($filename[$i])), 0, strpos(substr($filename[$i], strpos($filename[$i], $_POST['nprocesso'])+26, strlen($filename[$i])), '.pdf')).',';
             echo $nomes_pdfs[$i];
            }               
           $zip->close();

           $path = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$_POST['nprocesso'];
           $files = scandir($path);
           array_shift($files); array_shift($files); $_SESSION['quantidade_pdf'] = count($files);
           echo $_SESSION['quantidade_pdf'];
        }
      }
    ?>
```

My problem actually is partially on "pdf.php" where the window load with the values returned of the "content3". When is a single PDF, the window display normally, but when is a ZIP file with multiples PDF's, the first PDF display correctcly, but starting in the second and on, it doesn't display. show a this error: "Failed to load PDF document".

pdf.php code:

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(file_exists('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf') && is_file('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1).'.pdf')){
 $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
 $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$processo.'.pdf';
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 @readfile($file);
}else{
/////////////////////HERE IS THE PART WHEN IS A ZIP////////////////////////
///////*This part it's only to check if the folder extract exists*/////////
 function folder_exist($folder){ $path = realpath($folder); return ($path !== false AND is_dir($path)) ? $path : false; }
 chdir('//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/');
 $folder = '/'.substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/')).'/';
 if(FALSE !== ($path = folder_exist($folder))){
 /////*Here start the part where the code catch the PDF's and display*/////
  $pasta = substr(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), 0, strpos(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'p/')+2), '/'));
  $processo = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
  $file = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  $filename = '//dsbimrj16/Vinculacao_Cadastro_Gestor/'.$pasta.'/'.$processo.'.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
 }else{
  die('<h2 style="background-color:#FA5858"><center>Não foi encontrado a inicial do processo. Verifique se o mesmo encontra-se na pasta.</center></h2>');
 }
}
?>
```

What i'm doing wrong ? I've already checked the folder, the file is in and the name and the path is the same that the code are putting to display

Comment: I am not for sure at all what the question is, so I bet this question will be closed in the next 10 minutes.

Comment: This question is why my code on the "pdf.php" file are not showing the PDF's starting on the second